# I don't know why the variables are not initializing, all variables declared inside if statements aren't recognized

Tags: java

I can't figure out why the variables aren't being able to be printed

```
 import java.text.*;
   import java.io.*;

   public class CoffeeBags
   {

   //CONSTANTS
   public static final double SINGLE_PRICE = 5.5;

      public static void main( String[]args)
      throws IOException 
      {

      BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

       //Display Message "Enter Number of Bags Ordered: "
       System.out.print("Enter Number of Bags Ordered: ");
       //Save input as string
       String inputStr = br.readLine();
       //Verify that input is integer
       int numBags = Integer.parseInt(inputStr);
       //Make sure number is above 0
       if (numBags <= 0) 
            System.out.print("Please purchase at least one bag.");
       if (numBags <= 0) 
            System.exit(0);

       //Calculate purchase price
       double purchasePrice = SINGLE_PRICE * numBags;

       //Set numBagsLeft to numBags
       int numBagsLeft = numBags;

       //Determine Number of Large Boxes needed
       if (numBagsLeft >= 20) {
           int largeBoxCount = numBagsLeft / 20;
       }

       //Reinitialize Number of Bags to the remainder
       int numBagsLeft2 = numBagsLeft % 20;

       if (numBagsLeft2 >= 10) { 
           int mediumBoxCount = numBagsLeft2 / 10;
       };

       int numBagsLeft3 = numBagsLeft2 % 10;

       if (numBagsLeft3 > 0 && numBagsLeft3 <= 5){ 
           int smallBoxCount = 1;
       } else {
           int smallBoxCount = 2;
       }

       //Display 
       System.out.print("\n\nNumber of Bags ordered: " + numBags + " - " + purchasePrice 
       + "\nBoxesUsed: "
       + "\n            "+largeBoxCount+" Large - $+largeBoxCount*1.80
       + "\n            "+mediumBoxCount+" Medium - $"+mediumBoxCount*1.00
       + "\n            "+smallBoxCount+" Small - $"+smallBoxCount*.60
       + "\n\nYour total cost is: $"+largeBoxCount*1.80+mediumBoxCount*1.00+smallBoxCount*.60+purchasePrice;;)
       }


}
```

---

Okay. So the code is supposed to take in a number of "Coffee Bags", and then, using a system of if statements, filter down through in order to find out how many boxes you will need to purchase in order to best save money. The problem I'm having is that the variables such as largeBoxCount and mediumBoxCount are not being initialized, and thus aren't able to be called when I go to print them.

Comment: Please put in a little more effort to describe your program and your problem. What is the code supposed to be doing? what is it not doing? Are you seeing errors? What are they? Where are they? Please help us out here, we're volunteers, and your question is truthfully little more than a very sparse description and a code dump. Sorry, but this is a lazy question and should be and can be improved.

Comment: Okay. So the code is supposed to take in a number of "Coffee Bags", and then, using a system of if statements, filter down through in order to find out how many boxes you will need to purchase in order to best save money. The problem I'm having is that the variables such as largeBoxCount and mediumBoxCount are not being initialized, and thus aren't able to be called when I go to print them.

Comment: If you want to improve your question, please *edit the question to improve it* rather than posting comments trying to explain it.

Comment: I have edited your question with the additional information. In the future, please add this from the get-go. Please read the [help] section for more on this, especially the sub-section on how to ask good questions. Following these recommendations will decrease our frustration and get you better answers, so it's a win-win if you do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some scoping issues. Variables declared inside of an if block are visible only inside the if block and not outside of it. Declare those variables before the if blocks and in the main method.

```
bar = 0; // declared before the if block, visible inside and out
if (foo) {
   bar = 1; // this variable is visible outside of the if block
   int baz = 1; // this variable is not visible outside of the if block
}

System.out.println("bar = " + bar); // legal
System.out.println("baz = " + baz); // illegal
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the variables *inside* the if statements, when the scope ends they are removed.